# Real Time Carrier Shipping with a Test Shopify website

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to use real-time carrier shipping rates in a Test Shopify website?

We provide fulfillment services for a client who is using Shopify and we would like to test this feature along with our import routines before the client goes live with real-time rates.

Comment: Send us the name of your test store and we'll enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [the carrier service API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/carrierservice) works on [development stores that have been created from a partners account.](https://help.shopify.com/partners/getting-started/development-stores)